# How to use puppeteer to dump WebSocket data

Tags: websocket, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I want to get websocket data in this page https://upbit.com/exchange?code=CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-BTC, its websocket URL is dynamic and only valid during the first connection, the second time you connect to it it will not send data anymore.

[image]

So I wonder that maybe headless chrome can help me to monitor the websocket data.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: See also [Capturing Websocket Messages From Network Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893407/capturing-websocket-messages-from-network-tab)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You actually don't need to do anything complex on this. The URL though seems dynamic, but works fine through code as well. The reason it doesn't work is that you need to understand what is happening in the background.

First let's look at the Network Tab.

[image: Websocket URL]

The cookies and the Origin may be of importance to connecting. So we note these down.

Now let us look at the data exchanges on the socket

[image: Starting frames]

[image: Middle frames]

If you look at the frames the initial frame receives `o` as the data, which may indicate a opening connection. And then the website sends some data to the socket, which may be related to what we want to query. When the connection gets halted for some time, the socket receives `h` as the data. This may indicated a hold or something (as shown in second image)

To get the exact data we put a breakpoint in the code

[image: Breakpoint]

And then print the value in the console

[image: data sent]

Now we have enough information to hit to the coding part. I found below to be a good websocket library for this

https://github.com/websockets/ws

So we do a

```
yarn add ws || npm install ws --save
```

Now we write our code

```
const WebSocket = require("ws")
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://example.com/sockjs/299/enavklnl/websocket",null,{
    headers: {
        "Cookie":"<cookie data noted earlier>",
        "User-Agent": "<Your browser agent>"
    },
    origin: "https://example.com",
})
const opening_message = '["[{\\"ticket\\":\\"ram macbook\\"},{\\"type\\":\\"recentCrix\\",\\"codes\\":[\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-BTC\\",\\"CRIX.BITFINEX.USD-BTC\\",\\"CRIX.BITFLYER.JPY-BTC\\",\\"CRIX.OKCOIN.CNY-BTC\\",\\"CRIX.KRAKEN.EUR-BTC\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-DASH\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-ETH\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-NEO\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-BCC\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-MTL\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-LTC\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-STRAT\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-XRP\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-ETC\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-OMG\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-SNT\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-WAVES\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-PIVX\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-XEM\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-ZEC\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-XMR\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-QTUM\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-LSK\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-STEEM\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-XLM\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-ARDR\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-KMD\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-ARK\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-STORJ\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-GRS\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-VTC\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-REP\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-EMC2\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-ADA\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-SBD\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-TIX\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-POWR\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-MER\\",\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-BTG\\",\\"CRIX.COINMARKETCAP.KRW-USDT\\"]},{\\"type\\":\\"crixTrade\\",\\"codes\\":[\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-BTC\\"]},{\\"type\\":\\"crixOrderbook\\",\\"codes\\":[\\"CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-BTC\\"]}]"]'
ws.on('open', function open() {
    console.log("opened");
});

ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
    if (data == "o" || data == "h") {
        console.log("sending opening message")
        ws.send(opening_message)
    }
    else {
        console.log("Received", data)

    }
});
```

And running the code we get

[image: Working code]

Now if I replace

```
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://example.com/sockjs/299/enavklnl/websocket",null,{
    headers: {
        "Cookie":"<cookie data noted earlier>",
        "User-Agent": "<Your browser agent>"
    },
    origin: "https://example.com",
})
```

to

```
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://example.com/sockjs/299/enavklnl/websocket")
```

Which means `cookies` and `origin` was never needed as such. But I would still recommend you to use them

Comment: If you just want to do this using puppeteer only, then this may not be the answer you were looking for

Comment: Amazing answer, very detailed and enlightening analysis. I'll adopt your answer under another question https://stackoverflow.com/q/48364820/381712, for this question I still want to know how to dump data via Puppeteer or headless Chrome

Comment: Is there a way to do this with `puppeteer` only?

Comment: @Stophface, puppeteer is automating the browser, so as long as you get the data on the page to capture, you can do it. If not then you will have to resort to such ways

Comment: How do you understand where to place your breakpoint? I can't find '.send(' phrase in js files.

Answer (score 38):

```js
// for old puppeteer
// const client = page._client
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession()

await client.send('Network.enable')
    
client.on('Network.webSocketCreated', ({requestId, url}) => {
  console.log('Network.webSocketCreated', requestId, url)
})
    
client.on('Network.webSocketClosed', ({requestId, timestamp}) => {
  console.log('Network.webSocketClosed', requestId, timestamp)
})
    
client.on('Network.webSocketFrameSent', ({requestId, timestamp, response}) => {
  console.log('Network.webSocketFrameSent', requestId, timestamp, response.payloadData)
})

client.on('Network.webSocketFrameReceived', ({requestId, timestamp, response}) => {
  console.log('Network.webSocketFrameReceived', requestId, timestamp, response.payloadData)
})
```

It is by using DevTools protocol directly - https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#event-webSocketClosed

Comment: how to respond with mock data though?

Comment: Looks like the only way for now is to intercept the websocket connection request and redirect it to your own websocket server. Maybe this can be helpful https://forum.katalon.com/t/intercepting-request-with-chrome-devtools-protocol/36081

Comment: @zag2art, Sorry to bring up a 2 year old question, but please explain how to call Network.webSocketFrameReceived ? Should I specify all three parameters when calling this function? Or just two RequestId and MonotonicTime ?

Comment: @Optimus1, just copy the whole example and take a look. these three are not parameters you need to specify. they are callback parameters, so you will get them.

Comment: I am afraid this does not work anylonger in Puppeteer version 15 (maybe even earlier): `TypeError: client.on is not a function`. Any solutions?

My proposal: change `page._client` to `page._client()`.

Comment: probably const client = await page.target().createCDPSession()

Comment: This worked for me only after I added `await client.send('Network.enable');`

Answer (score 6):

I don't think puppeteer has support for this yet, but the lower-level protocol *does* here: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-webSocketFrameSent and https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#type-WebSocketResponse. This means that you could implement this yourself in a library if you wanted too.