# Recording binary WebSocket data using Puppeteer

Tags: websocket, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm trying to record realtime data that is streamed through a WebSocket using Puppeteer. I've followed the instructions on [How to use puppeteer to dump WebSocket data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375700/how-to-use-puppeteer-to-dump-websocket-data), but haven't had any luck so far. The `Network.webSocketFrameReceived` callback is never triggered. I tried doing the same for `Network.webSocketFrameSent` and other websocket events, and none of them are triggered.

I've run puppeteer with `DEBUG=puppeteer:*` and dont' see the websocket events, although HTTP/Fetch events are logged. Does CDP have a limitation with binary websockets?

Using the latest stable version of Pupeeteer (1.20.0)

Comment: Turned out to be a weird quirk of the app I was trying to automate. The WebSocket connection itself was being handled inside a WebWorker, and hence the issue. Works fine when the WebWorker is disabled.

Comment: Sorry to bring up a 2 year old question, but please explain how to call Network.webSocketFrameReceived ? Should I specify all three parameters when calling this function? Or just two
RequestId and
MonotonicTime ?