# Detecting socket.io events in an HTML game

Tags: html, node.js, sockets, socket.io, puppeteer

I'm attempting to use puppeteer to detect certain socket.io events emitted by the game, such as these:

```
socket.on("setStartTime", socket_onSetStartTime);
socket.on("nextTurn", socket_onNextTurn);
socket.on("livesLost", socket_onLivesLost);
socket.on("bonusAlphabetCompleted", socket_onBonusAlphabetCompleted);
socket.on("setPlayerWord", socket_onSetPlayerWord);
socket.on("failWord", socket_onFailWord);
socket.on("correctWord", socket_onCorrectWord);
socket.on("happyBirthday", socket_onHappyBirthday);
```

Is there a way to do this with puppeteer or something else in node?

Comment: Did you try [How to use puppeteer to dump WebSocket data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375700/how-to-use-puppeteer-to-dump-websocket-data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to create a CDP session, [as listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375700/how-to-use-puppeteer-to-dump-websocket-data).

Example:

```
const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await cdp.send("Network.enable");
await cdp.send("Page.enable");

cdp.on("Network.webSocketFrameReceived", handleResponse); // Fired when WebSocket message is received.
cdp.on("Network.webSocketFrameSent", handleResponse); // Fired when WebSocket message is sent.

function handleResponse(packet) {
    //do stuff with packet
}
```