# Accessing buttons within an iframe using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, iframe, puppeteer

I am trying to access a button within an iframe on this site: https://jklm.fun/?fromOldGames (the bomb party rooms).

The button in question is this one:
[image]

I have been able to access the iframe as such `let frame = await page.frames()[0];` however when I try grab the button by class name it apparently doesn't exist and when I grab every `button` element on the page/in the frame like this `let buttons = await frame.$$("button");` they are all "Unclickable nodes or not HTMLElements".

I was able to tell that the buttons are being returned as ElementHandles but according to puppeteer docs I should be able to use the `click()` method.

I'm not quite sure why the handles would be unclickable or what I need to do to change that.

*Somewhat unrelated, `page.$$("button")` and `frame.$$("button")` both return exactly 8 element handles while there are 11 buttons on the page, is there a reasonable explanation for this as well?*

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
const frame = await iframe.contentFrame();

await frame.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector(".join").children.click();
}).then(async() => {

}
```

If you got an update to your post : [Detecting socket.io events in an HTML game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73988063/detecting-socket-io-events-in-an-html-game/74715311#74715311), please edit it

Comment: how are you fetching the frame? im getting "contentFrame(); is not a function"

Comment: `page.waitForSelector("iframe").then(() => {
    page.$("iframe").then(async (iframe) => {
        const frame = await iframe.contentFrame();
    });
});
`
You should check this repo : https://github.com/IsaacLaquerre/BombPartyBot, has everything you need