# puppeteer not capturing websocket requests

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      executablePath: chromePaths.chrome,
      headless: false,
      devtools: true
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setRequestInterception(true);

    page.on('request', (request) => {
        console.log(request.url());
        request.continue();
    });

    await Promise.all([
      page.goto(`https://example.com/live?&session=${session}`),
      page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
    ]);
    
await page.waitForSelector("#video");
await page.click(".share__VideWrapper-wtg3fv-4");

    //not capturing websocket requests after click
```

If I run this function for this URL: "https://example.com/live?&session=${session}", I should get "wss://ws-feed.pro.coinbase.com/" in the log after click the page, but that is not the case.

What happens instead?
The websocket URL does not get logged.

Comment: `page.goto` already waits for navigation, so `page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })` is at best pointless and at worst possibly incorrect. Use `page.goto({waitUntil: "networkidle0"})`, although networkidle0 is generally discouarged. Is example.com your actual site? If not, please provide an actual site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use puppeteer to dump WebSocket data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375700/how-to-use-puppeteer-to-dump-websocket-data)